# add items to a list from a different thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a class as:

```
class SomeClass{

    class Connection{//some fields}

    static List<Connection> connections { get; set; }


     public SomeClass( \\params etc)
     {

       connections = new List<Connections>(); // initialize connections list

      //initialize some other private vars
      // ...

       mainClassThreadMethod();
     }

    private void mainClassThreadMethod()
    {
        while (true)
        {

            Thread t;
            Connection p = new Connection ( { \\instantiate the class})
            // this code will not execute until p is initialized...  In other words this loop will not execute several times quickly. 

            t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(startThread));
            t.Start(p);
        }
    }



    private void startThread(object o)
    {
        //add a new connection to the list
        connections.Add((Connection)o));
    }

    public List<Connection> getConnections()
    {
        return connections;
    }

}
```

why is it that after adding new connections to the list if I then call the getConnections method it returns a null list? I figure it is because I am adding the items from a different thread. How can I keep track of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems in the code above, but sticking to the question asked, to synchronize the list (allow adding from different threads) you can **(1) implement your own locking, or (2) use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3azh197k.aspx.**

I'd go for #2, but in your case:

- No, it's probably not caused by adding anything from a different thread
- Why would you even want to add from inside `startThread`? You have the connection object before you instantiate a thread, so you can easily call `connections.Add(connection)` from the same thread thereby eliminating the need for any locking.
- Why is there a while(true) loop around the thread spin-up process?

Comment: I have a program that synchronizes some of my files between multiple computers on the same network. One computer acts as a server. I want to  be able to establish multiple connections. because the NetworkStream.Read(.. method is NOT asynchronous I have to be listening for connections on separate threads. I know very little about multithreading. But from researching in google I think I have to do something with locking so you are right...

Comment: In that case what you normally do is have one listener thread which then reacts on incoming connections either by spinning up new threads or doing some other things. I'll try and find a link for you.

Comment: Here you go: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server this should cover what you want nicely.